# Please don't migrate crap to SO

Tags: discussion, migration, stackoverflow

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/255703/revisions

It should be obvious that this question will be downvoted and closed within moments. Please don't migrate crap to SO.

Perhaps this site should have a close reason like SO does for things that belong on SU but are too crappy to be migrated?

Comment: Related on MSO [Add a “don't migrate crap” migration 'path' to all sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225006/213963)

Comment: And also the request for adding another close reason of "this question is off topic here, and is crap on SO" - [close reason (and associated expand the close reason count) request](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6106/40980)... and my [custom close reason for when I copy and paste it](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6252/40980)

Comment: Although this one was posted first, I closed it as a duplicate of the other since I felt the other was a better worded question.

Comment: @ThomasOwens that's fine :)

Comment: Programmers has a history of migrating crap posts off their site...